Shape of Trace of Chalk on a Blackboard (Kinematics problem)

A white piece of chalk is thrown onto a black horizontal board moving at constant velocity. Initially, the chalk's velocity was perpendicular to the board's direction of motion. What  is the shape of the chalk's trace on the board?


 I've drawn out the situation in this. All of this is in the horizontal plane. The green arrow is the chalk's velocity and blue the board's. It's like we've rolled the chalk onto the board, I suppose (but vertically).  
I saw this problem in Kalda Kinematics. Since the board has been placed horizontally and friction will act opposite to the direction of motion of the chalk, the trace should be a straight line.
I don't need help with the question. I'm just confused with the cases I thought of. I couldn't figure things out clearly in the scenarios listed below.

What if the horizontal board was accelerating? The chalk would follow a parabolic path, right? And kinetic friction would act tangentially at every point? I don't know if this is right. How does friction in such a case affect the trajectory of the chalk trace?

What if the board was shifted and placed vertically? Now there's an additional mg acting downwards. That should reduce the vertical component of velocity. In this case, I'm guessing it would result in some complicated shape. I feel so because there's acceleration along both the axes. Is this conclusion right?


I would appreciate if somebody could help put things in perspective.

P.S. The doubts I have are just connected to the question and not regarding the solution of the question. I wish to know more about the cases I've come up with. About how the trajectories will be affected. It's only related to the content of the problem.

Chalk trace represents movement style of board. If it moves straight, even with acceleration,- why chalk should leave curved path ? Curved path would be just in case board is rotating or does not move in a straight line.

This is a terrible question. Two immediate ambiguities can be seen: (1) "moving at constant velocity" - in which direction ? Horizontally or vertically ? (2) "Initially, the chalk's velocity was perpendicular to the board's direction of motion" - when is "initially" ? Is it when the chalk was thrown ? Or when it hit the board ? Also, is the chalk moving vertically or horizontally or neither ?

@gandalf61 Yeah, the question doesn't provide details. I'll try to add an illustration based on what I could make out.

@gandalf61 I've added an illustration. I hope it makes things clear. As to what "initially" implies, I'm guessing it's when it starts moving on the board as shown in the figure I've drawn.
